# How can I run my WebApplication files to the server without an Index.html or.php?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, xampp, htdocs

I have been looking everywhere around the internet and cannot find how to just simply run my Web Application files. I tried using XAMPP with Joomal but it wouldn't let me just use my own files I had to create a template or just add to an existing one.

I am trying to run TinyMce, Htm, php, and js.  But once I add my files to the htdocs folder in XAMPP it just shows me a file directory to navigate the folders and not run and present my web site.  [Here is an example](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z_bOgisKuBb5OQvjZ0PcIUthj2ADusMTnXHKxichSIo/edit?usp=sharing) of what exactly is happening.

Comment: have you tried calling index.php explicitly?

Comment: Do you access it via http://localhost/.... and not via file://

Comment: @AndréSchild see the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch off the [Directory Listings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings), either in the apache configuration (preferably) or in the .htaccess file.

In httpd.conf, find the root directory of your website, and add `Options -Indexes`:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you guide me to how to do that?

Comment: The httpd.conf of Apache?

Comment: How do i find the root directory?

Comment: Yes, the httpd.conf of Apache. How the root directory is shown depends a bit, sometimes it is just a /

Comment: I added another screeshot https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z_bOgisKuBb5OQvjZ0PcIUthj2ADusMTnXHKxichSIo/edit

Comment: If you see </Directory> somewhere, that's *probably* the right one.

Comment: Did you see the screenshot of the conf file?  There is multiple fields in the <directory tag> where do i put the options -Indexes

Comment: There's already an `Options Indexes` there - just put a minus sign in front of `Indexes`.

Comment: Can you please highlight where you see that?

Comment: When I did that Apache failed to start back up...Check the link ^ up there for the screenshot of it.

Comment: That's strange - do you see any error messages in the log?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the log to the doc.

Comment: OK, it seems it works now - you don't get a directory listing anymore. What you now need to do is find out which .html or .php or other file is the starting point for your website, and type that as the last part of the address.

Comment: How do I locate the starting point for my website?  I got these files from a Web hosting service but recalled my content back to run my server at home.  I cant seem to find the start PHP or HTML though

Comment: Neither do I - I don't know Joomla that well. It might help if you know the starting point on the web hosting service.